# How to Inject dependencies inside a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection

I have 2 services. `CarsController` and `CarsFetcherService`

I also have a class called `Car`.

The CarsController has a method `createCar()` that creates an instance of `Car` everytime it is called.
Each `Car` instance needs to be provided with the `CarsController` service.

With the code below, each `Car` instances gets undefined instead of the CarsController dependency.
I use the library `typedi` to illustrate the problem I want to know in general how this is done. An answer with other library link inversify or Nestjs or even `Angular` would also be helpful.

```
export class Car {
    @Inject() // this is not working here
    private carsController: CarsController; // this becomes undefined
    private carRecipe: string;

    constructor(carRecipe: string) {
        this.carRecipe = carRecipe;
        this.carsController.notifyNetwork('HelloWorld, I am created!');
    }
}

@Service()
export class CarsController {

    @Inject()
    private carsNetworkService: CarsFetcherService;
    private cars: Car[] = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    createCar() {
        const carRecipe = this.carsNetworkService.getRequestSomething();
        const car = new Car(carRecipe);
        this.cars.push(car);
    }

    notifyNetwork(msg: string) {
        this.carsNetworkService.postRequestSomething(msg);
    }
}

@Service()
export class CarsFetcherService {
    getRequestSomething() {
        return 'this is how to make a car';
    }

    postRequestSomething(msg:string) {
        console.log(msg)
    }
}

const carsController = Container.get(CarsController)
// Creating 4 cars
carsController.createCar()
carsController.createCar()
carsController.createCar()
carsController.createCar()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that when using `typedi`, and other similar DI frameworks, you should separate your classes into two categories. First categories would be services: `typedi` would guarantee that there's only one instance of each, `typedi` would create those instances and inject everything. Second category would be ordinary objects, that you create and manage on your own.

So, if you want to create as many instances of `Car` as you like, don't use DI for it - you already create it in a service that has direct references to everything `Car` needs:

```
export class Car {
    // deleted inject decorator

    constructor(private carsController, private carRecipe: string) {
        this.carsController.notifyNetwork('HelloWorld, I am created!');
    }
}

@Service()
export class CarsController {

    @Inject()
    private carsNetworkService: CarsFetcherService;
    private cars: Car[] = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    createCar() {
        const carRecipe = this.carsNetworkService.getRequestSomething();
        const car = new Car(this, carRecipe);
        this.cars.push(car);
    }

    notifyNetwork(msg: string) {
        this.carsNetworkService.postRequestSomething(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it not advisable to use DI on ordinary objects ? Or is anti-pattern or something else ?